# How to enable Program has stopped working dialog?

Tags: windows-10

When apps crash, Windows used to popup a dialog box saying `{Program} has stopped working` with a `Close` button. I no longer see this dialog box on Windows 10. How do I get it back?

I thought perhaps I messed up some registry setting, so I downloaded a [Windows 10 VM from Microsoft](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/), crashed a program in the VM and I still didn't get a dialog box. So there must have been some change to Windows.

I tried tweaking the AeDebug registry key, but still couldn't get the dialog box back.

The reason I like the dialog box is because it tells me right away that some program has a problem that I can investigate further.

Comment: That is new in WIndows 10, it now only adds an entry to the Application event log and no longer displays the WER dialog.  Superuser.com is the right place to ask about this.

Comment: Thanks, I found a [similar question at Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/q/1246626/366315) and figured out a [partial answer](https://superuser.com/a/1349113/366315).

Answer (score 2):

As described [here](https://superuser.com/a/1349113/366315), you need to set the Windows Error Reporting setting DontShowUI=0 with the Registry Editor or Group Policy Editor.

Answer (score 0):

sounds a little dumb when i tell that but, when app stops working for me i usually press the left mouse button a lot in the windows (of the app) until it will display the message to end the process

Comment: That probably works because Windows 10's hang / not responding reporting still shows a dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the registry editor:

1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting`.
2. Create a DWORD, name it `DontShowUI` and leave its value at 0 (if it already exists, set its value to 0).